# How to migrate from hosted TFS to on-premises TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration

How can I migrate from TFS hosted on http://tfs.visualstudio.com to an on-premises version of TFS?  I want to use [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Express 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30675), which is free for 5 users.

Can everything be migrated including work items, queries, and source code?

Answer (score 2):

The TFS Integration Platform can do this, however it has its limitations. A major one is that source history is played back change by change, which means you lose the original dates that things happened.

Willy P Schaub wrote an excellent msdn magazine article on [Migrating from an On-Premises Team Foundation Server to Team Foundation Service Preview Using the TFS Integration Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj130558.aspx) which is the opposite direction than you want, but it should be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the Data Export to move your data from VSO to TFS on-prem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cb80f0d-0119-4277-82e8-719a8db1796e

Comment: the link is moved